# Itextsharp adding border to all pdf pages

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am adding Big table( approx cover 4 to 5 pages in pdf) in PDF.
I am using below code to add Big table( approx cover 4 to 5 pages in pdf) in PDF. (Code working Fine)

```
private static String CreateTableDocument()
    {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 50, 50);


        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("D:\\ttt.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
          // GetTable("1") is my custom method that will return big table that cover 4 to 5 pages -- no problem here -
        document.Add(GetTable("1"));

        document.Close();
        return "";
    }
```

Above code generate PDF successfully, Now i want to add border to all generated pages. 
I search through and found that it may be possible using `PdfContentByte` or `Rectangle` but its not adding border to all pages or may be i am missing something.

Other option may be possible using `PageEvent` but i am using WEB API so may be not possible to implement event listener.

**UPDATE:**
My class definition is like below: (is it possible to override Page Event (onEndPage))

```
public class PDFTaskController : ApiController
{
 // here my all pdf task related methods i.e. CreateTableDocument()
}
```

Comment: Whenever you want to do something *to all generated pages* in a similar manner, you usually use page events (more precisely their `onEndPage`) for that. There you use `PdfContentByte` methods as you have read about.

Comment: Yes. but i am using WEB API so it is not possible to override onEndPage.

Comment: Why would WEB API prevent the use of `onEndPage`? That sounds absurd. Have you even tried using page events?

Comment: Hello @BrunoLowagie, i think for using onEndPage i need to implement interface to my class. and i am unable to do that.

Comment: Define "to my class". You need to extend `PdfPageEventHelper` and use that extension as the event for `PdfWriter`.

Comment: "to my class" is PDFTaskController that already extend ApiController

Comment: Let me try. i will back if it not work

Comment: You are not limited to putting everything into your controller, you can use multiple own classes in addition to it.

Comment: @ButaniVijay Have you succeeded?

Comment: Yes i will come out with other solution. Thanks for your timely support and advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have onEndPage, you can try following code:

```
 //Add border to page
    PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(document.PageSize);
    rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin;
    rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
    rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin;
    rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;
    content.SetColorStroke(Color.BLACK);
    content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
    content.Stroke();
```

According to [this](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/151175/How-to-add-border-to-PDF-page-using-iTextSharp-in-C-Net/).

Comment: I dont think it will add border to all pages.

Comment: its adding to last page only

Comment: Code hat you have provided will not add border to all page

Comment: Indeed: that code adds a rectangle to the *current* page. It doesn't add a rectangle to *every* page. This post doesn't answer the question; it should be removed, or improved. Improved: either explain how to use page events; or explain how to add the rectangle in a second pass.